# Can we still merge a Github Pull Request if the creator's account is deleted

Tags: github, merge, pull-request

We have pending pull requests from a former colleague, and are wandering if we need to merge these PRs in case he deletes his Github account.

Is there someone who tried? I did not find an answer in the Github documentation.

Comment: I'd assume you can't, but I don't have any proof. Deleting an account should also delete all repositories, causing the fork to vanish. You could, however, just pull the remote branch (that you want to merge) into it's own branch in your repo now and merge that later. This way, you'll preserve the changes without affecting your default branch

Comment: When users delete their accounts, all their PRs are automatically closed; you can't just merge it using GitHub UI. You could check the modified files and update them directly in your `master` branch (that's easy but could take a bit of time depending on the files).